# Tkinter canvas default width = '10c'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was looking through the tkinter widgets at https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm and noticed that the width configure option for the canvas defaults to '10c'

```
width=
    Canvas width. Default value is ‘10c’. (width/Width)
```

What does that mean? What effect does that have on how its width is handled by pack and grid geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: `Canvas` default `width` = `'10c'`, What does that mean?

**Reference**:

- [width](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M11)

  > Specifies a desired window width that the `Canvas` widget should request from its geometry manager. The value may be specified in any of the forms described in the COORDINATES section below.
- [COORDINATES](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M17)

  > Coordinates and distances are specified in screen units, which are floating-point numbers optionally followed by one of several letters `m|c|p`.
  >
  > - If **no letter** is supplied then the distance is in **pixels**.
  > - If it is `c` then the distance is in **centimeters**;

Comment: I read in *[COORDINATES](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.html#M17)*, that there are *four* units besides pixels of which **`i`** is not in your list. I observed it to be working on Windows. Is this a new feature?